# jQuery mobile reloads iFrame on panel opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, iframe

I have stumbled upon this weird problem, where an iframe in the content area of a jQuery mobile site is reloaded the first time I open a panel. Any subsequent opening does not reload the iFrame.

You can see it in action in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jakobgt1/Z3mmn/7/ (watch the network requests).

```
<body>
<div data-role="page">
  <div id="nav-panel" data-role="panel">
    <a href="#my-header" data-rel="close">Close panel</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
      <a href= "#nav-panel" data-role="button">FooBar</a>
      <iframe src="http://gedefar.dk/"/>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

If I replace the iframe with anything else it is not reloaded (such as a picture - http://jsfiddle.net/jakobgt1/GdKu2/1/):

```
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff"/>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.10.1, jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 RC-1.

Is it a bug, or is there something I have missed?

---

Updated answer:

By wrapping the content div inside a ui-panel-wrapper div the iFrame is not reloaded. (See the original fiddle with just an 8 instead of a 7 in the URL, as I can't post more than two links)

```
 <div class="ui-panel-wrapper">
   <div data-role="content">
       <a href= "#nav-panel" data-role="button">FooBar</a>
       <iframe src="http://gedefar.dk/"/>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Jakob

Comment: When panel first open, it wraps _header_, _footer_ and _content_ divs in `ui-panel-wrapper`, therefore, _content_ div contents get reloaded. In previous versions, this step is perform once _panel_ widget is auto-initiated/created. Also note that it happens when `data-display` is either _push_ or _reveal_.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! And indeed using  data-display="overlay" ensures that the page is not reloaded.  But how come the image then is not reloaded? Is that because of how the browser handles dom changes wrt. to iframes and images?

Comment: maybe because image is cached unlike external URL inside a frame.

Comment: Ok. Thank anyways for the explanation. I have updated the question with the solution.

Comment: You're welcome :) Add it as an answer, dont update your question with a solution.

Comment: Ahh good point, I'm new to the site. And as I'm new on this site I can't post an answer to my own question before tomorrow. But will do then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Thanks to Omar I realized that by wrapping the content div inside a ui-panel-wrapper div, the iFrame is not reloaded, as this is then not done by jQuery mobile. (See the original fiddle with just an 8 instead of a 7 in the URL, as I can't post more than two links).

```
<div class="ui-panel-wrapper">
 <div data-role="content">
   <a href= "#nav-panel" data-role="button">FooBar</a>
   <iframe src="http://gedefar.dk/"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Jakob